# Sybase Delete command not working as expected

Tags: sybase

I wrote this simple commands to test the delete command but found some discrepancies with it:

```
delete table1 from table1,table2
where table1.col1 = table2.col1
and table1.col2= table2.col2
```

In table1 I have 272768 rows, table2 I have 1380 rows. Now I need to remove these 1380 rows available in table2 from table1. But to my surprise it removed 2234 rows from table1 after running the above script. The expected removal should be only 1380 rows. Is there anything I can do to optimize this ?

Comment: Could it be duplicate rows in Table1 that are throwing your expected vs actual results?  What happens if you do a count(*) instead of delete?

Comment: count(*) of table 2 gives me 1380 rows

Comment: What you've written is a syntax error, isn't it?  You'd need an AND between the two terms in the WHERE clause, wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes, thats a typing error, I just corrected it. The and is there in my original script which i'm running on the db.

Comment: Is this [tag:sybase-asa], [tag:sybase-ase], [tag:sybase-iq], or [tag:sqlanywhere]? Trying to clean up the [tag:sybase] tag...

Comment: It's Sybase ASE, adaptive sybase enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
delete from table1 
from  table2
where table1.col1 = table2.col1
and table1.col2= table2.col2
```

or

```
delete from table1 
where exists 
(
  select 1
    from table2 
  where table1.col1 = table2.col1
    and table1.col2= table2.col2

)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I did try this just now. The result is same 2234 rows. I just want it to delete those 1380 rows. i reconfirmed the number of rows in table 2, it is 1380... Don't know whats wrong.

Comment: @user726720 I added one more solution.

Comment: yes it's still the same thing. Okay let me give you more insights into this. Table1 is the original table, table2 I imported it from a txt file. I cleared some data got 1380 rows which I'm planning to remove from table1 and copy some new rows into table1. Now table2, doesn't have any pk's or indexes set on it. Do you think this as a reason for it not working properly.

Comment: I imported table2 from a text file using bcp, the column names are similar on both tables but  the only exception being there are no pk's or indexes set on column2. is this necessary for this to work

Comment: Pls, try to run this query: `select count(1)
table1,table2
where table1.col1 = table2.col1
and table1.col2= table2.col2`

Comment: give me 10 mins. i'm just restoring my db on a test platform to do more tests

Comment: @Parado: The result of this query is 2234

Comment: @user726720 delete command works correctly. Michael Gardner has right, table1 has more rows you've expected.

Comment: Then the query is working perfectly fine.  You have a data validation issue.  There are duplicate records in table1 (based on col1 & col2), so some of the records in table2 match more than 1 record in table1.

Comment: So in this case, can I avoid deleting those conflicting records and removing the rest. How would I go about this ?

Comment: gotta go now, I will update on this tomorrow, please leave your comments in the meanwhile if you do find a solution. Thank you

Comment: True, there were duplicates in table1. I verified this by removing both the tables to excel and compared it.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM table1 JOIN table2
    ON table1.col1 = table2.col1 AND table1.col2 = table2.col2
```

you will find that the 1380 rows in `table2` match 2234 rows in `table1`, so the DELETE is doing exactly what it should do.

That query is the preferred form; you can use the antiquated notation without explicit joins:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM table1, table2
 WHERE table1.col1 = table2.col1 AND table1.col2 = table2.col2
```

But you should be using the explicit JOIN notation in anything you write; you should only need to know about the comma-separated list in the FROM clause for understanding old queries written in another millennium.

Comment: I can't use the first query. It gives me error on join (I'm using Sybase v. 11). For the second query it returns me 2234, but this not what I expect. I expect it to delete only 1380 ( avaliable in table2)

Comment: I didn't know that Sybase 11 (that's fairly old, isn't it?) did not support explicit JOIN; I live, I learn (and probably then forget). The SELECT result means that there are several entries in `table1` for at least some of the entries in `table2`. You can run queries such as `SELECT table1.col1, table1.col2, COUNT(*) FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.col1 = table2.col1 AND table1.col2 = table2.col2 GROUP BY table1.col1, table1.col2 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to get a list of the (col1,col2) pairs having duplicates. But the problem is in the data, not the DELETE; it is doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: sure mate, I will update you on this tomorrow, would do some more tests tomorrow and check